# How to drop all views in mysql database with stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, sql-view

I want my mysql server to drop all views in the database. I allready created an event for a stored procedure:

BEGIN

```
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE; 
DECLARE VIEW_NAME CHAR(255);
DECLARE VIEW_NAMES CURSOR FOR SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.views;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

OPEN VIEW_NAMES;

read_loop: LOOP    
    FETCH VIEW_NAMES INTO VIEW_NAME;
    IF done THEN
        LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;    
    DROP VIEW VIEW_NAME;
END LOOP;

CLOSE VIEW_NAMES;
```

END

However, this procedure produces the following error:

> Error Code: 1051. Unknown table 'view_name'

My guess is that my fetch statement isn't fetching for some reason. So I checked the select statement and it does have a resultset. Anyone any ideas on how to solve the error or how to go about dropping all views in a mysql database?

Comment: try this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlcheck.html

Comment: Why should i do a check?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) to execute these queries. Build a string 'DROP VIEW...', then execute statement using prepared statements.

For example -

```
...
read_loop: LOOP    
    FETCH VIEW_NAMES INTO VIEW_NAME;
    IF done THEN
        LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;    

    SET @query = CONCAT('DROP VIEW ', VIEW_NAME);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END LOOP;
...
```

---

Another variant, without opening cursor:

```
SET @views = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(table_schema, '.', table_name) INTO @views
  FROM information_schema.views 
  WHERE table_schema = 'database_name';

SET @views = CONCAT('DROP VIEW ', @views);
PREPARE stmt FROM @views;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

...modify WHERE condition as you wish.

Comment: Great! Didn't notice that a string should be build.

Comment: Always appreciate the "cursor-less" version.  Especially in MySQL.